# Is there a way I can delay the retry for a service bus message in an Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, retry-logic

I have a function which pulls messages off a subscription, and forwards them to an HTTP endpoint. If the endpoint is unavailable, an exception is thrown. When this happens, I would like to delay the next attempt of that specific message for a certain amount of time, e.g. 15 minutes. So far, I have found the following solutions:

- Catch the exception, sleep, then throw. This is a terrible solution, as I will be charged for CPU usage while it is sleeping, and it will affect the throughput of the function.
- Catch the exception, clone the message, set the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property and add it back to the queue. This is a nicer way, but it resets the delivery count, so an actual problem will never be dead-lettered, and it is resent to all subscriptions, when only one subscriber failed to process it.
- Catch the exception, and place the message on a storage queue instead. This means maintaining a storage queue to match each subscription, and having two functions instead of one.

What I would ideally like to happen is to catch the exception, and exit the function *without releasing the lock on the message*. That way, as soon as the lock expires the message will be retried again. However, it seems that after completing successfully, the function calls `Complete()` on the message, and after an exception is thrown, the function calls `Abandon()` on the message. Is it possible to bypass this, or to achieve the delay some other way?

Comment: If these exceptions don't happen too often, you could create a function with a timer that would only fire every 15 minutes and checks the dead letter queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will address your situation by offering that the flow you are proposing is better handled by a **LogicApp** over a pure function.

It's quite easy to implement the *wait/retry/dequeue next* pattern in a LogicApp since this type of flow control is exactly what LogicApps was designed for.

Comment: Yes, this definitely seems more like what I'm after, considering they have an `HTTP` action which lets you define the retry policy on `408`, `429` and `5XX` return codes. Now I need to figure out how to extract parts of the brokered message for the authorization header and the message body

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported natively through [retry policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp#retry-policies-preview), which were added to Azure Functions around November 2020 (preview). You can configure the retry policy as fixed-delay or exponential-backoff.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
[FixedDelayRetry(10, "00:15:00")]   // retries with a 15-minute delay
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("MyTopic", "MySubscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string myQueueItem) 
{
    // Forward message to HTTP endpoint, throwing exception if endpoint unavailable
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the ServiceBus engine running the function since it has a SB trigger is unaware of the function retry policy so if you have redelivery setup, the total amount of retry will be (SB max redelivery * function retry policy amount) which is most likely _not_ what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although still in preview (not recommended for production code), you could use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview). If you want to maintain the ability to manipulate objects in code, this is likely your best bet!

(+1 to LogicApp solution too!)