# When a message fails to process in a ServiceBusTrigger Azure Function, how can I delay processing the same message for x minutes?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an azure function that reads from a ServiceBus topic and calls a 3rd party service.  If the service is down, I would like to wait 5 minutes before trying to call it again with the same message.  How can I add a delay so the azure function doesn't abandon the message and immediately pick it back up again?

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("someTopic", 
     "someSubscription", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = 
     "ServiceBusConnection")] BrokeredMessage message) 
{
     CallService(bodyOfBrokeredMessage); //service is down

     //How do I add a delay so the message won't be reprocessed immediately thus quickly exhausting it's max delivery count?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Josh said, you could simply clone the original message, set up the scheduled enqueue time, send the clone and complete the original.

Well, it’s a shame that sending the clone and completing the original are not an atomic operation, so there is a very slim chance of us seeing the original again should the handling process crash at just the wrong moment.

And the other issue is that `DeliveryCount` on the clone will **always be 1**, because this is a brand new message. So we could infinitely resubmit and never get round to dead-lettering this message.

Fortunately, that can be fixed by adding our own **resubmit count** as a property of the message:

```
[FunctionName("DelayMessage")]
public static async Task DelayMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("MyQueue", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "MyConnection")]BrokeredMessage originalMessage,
            [ServiceBus("MyQueue", AccessRights.Send, Connection = "MyConnection")]IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage> newMessages,TraceWriter log)
{
     //handle any kind of error scenerio
     int resubmitCount = originalMessage.Properties.ContainsKey("ResubmitCount") ?  (int)originalMessage.Properties["ResubmitCount"] : 0;
     if (resubmitCount > 5)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("DEAD-LETTERING");
         originalMessage.DeadLetter("Too many retries", $"ResubmitCount is {resubmitCount}");
     }
     else
     {
         var newMessage = originalMessage.Clone();
         newMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
         await newMessages.AddAsync(newMessage);
     }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://markheath.net/post/defer-processing-azure-service-bus-message).

Also, it's quite easy to implement the wait/retry/dequeue next pattern in a LogicApp since this type of flow control is exactly what LogicApps was designed for. Please refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888188/is-there-a-way-i-can-delay-the-retry-for-a-service-bus-message-in-an-azure-funct?rq=1).

Comment: While not exactly what I was hoping for, this works for my use case.  Thanks.  Also, you have a small copy/paste typo in the code      (int)m.Properties["ResubmitCount"]

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create a new message and submit that message to the queue but set the ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc to be five minutes in the future.

```
        [FunctionName("DelayMessage")]
        public static async Task DelayMessage(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("MyQueue", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "MyConnection")]BrokeredMessage originalMessage,
            [ServiceBus("MyQueue", AccessRights.Send, Connection = "MyConnection")]IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage> newMessages,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            //handle any kind of error scenerio

            var newMessage = originalMessage.Clone();

            newMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);

            await newMessages.AddAsync(newMessage);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the [fixed delay retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp#fixed-delay-retry), which was added to Azure Functions around November 2020 (preview).

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
[FixedDelayRetry(10, "00:05:00")]   // retries with a 5-minute delay
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("someTopic", 
     "someSubscription", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = 
     "ServiceBusConnection")] BrokeredMessage message) 
{
     CallService(bodyOfBrokeredMessage); //service is down
}
```